# Discord.js setGame() not working anymore

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been coding my Discord bot using Discord.JS for about 2 months now and I've just recently noticed that my bot isn't saying that it's playing what I'm telling it. When I first coded the bot up until recently it worked just fine. Now the 3 discord bots I have aren't showing their games.

This is the code I'm using:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ready");
  bot.user.setGame("Type !help");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.setGame()` is deprecated now but you could use `.setPresence()` or you could use the `.setActivity()` which is the same thing and format as the `.setGame()`. 
Ex.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.user.setActivity('YouTube', { type: 'WATCHING' });
```

[Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) is a link to the documentation in case you wanted to change `'Watching'` to something else like `'Playing'`.

Comment: Thanx! But the type: part is not working for me. Help please?

Comment: @ChristofferHjärtström make sure you used all caps and put it in exactly how I did. Check out the documentation I put in as well for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

`setGame()` is now deprecated, and discord.js asks you to use `setActivity()`.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ready");
  bot.user.setActivity("Type !help");
})
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

The setGame() Method has stopped working, here's what you can do:

- update to latest 11.1-dev or
- use `.setPresence({ game: { name: 'nameGoesHere', type: 0 } });` as a workaround instead

Source: https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/issues/1807#issuecomment-323578919

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short example of using the .setPresence that LW001 linked to:

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', () => {
    bot.user.setStatus('available') // Can be 'available', 'idle', 'dnd', or 'invisible'
    bot.user.setPresence({
        game: {
            name: 'Type !help',
            type: 0
        }
    });
});
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setGame

Answer (score 0):

`setgame` is depreciated use `setActivity` instead

example:

```
client.user.setActivity('activity here')
```

Or:

```
client.user.setActivity('activity here', {type: "WATCHING"})
```

type can be `WATCHING`, `LISTENING`, `PLAYING` or `STREAMING`

if streaming you need to add this below the `setActivity` code

```
url: "twitch.tv/urtwitchusername",
```