# client.user.setGame() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot display the "Playing: ..." message but it doesn't work. I'm using `client.user.setGame("test")`, but I also tried `client.user.setPresence()` but it didn't work too. If I log `client.user` I can see that the presence is

```
localPresence:
{ status: 'online',
  game: { name: 'test', url: undefined },
  afk: false,
  since: 0 },
```

So, even if the presence seems to be defined properly it isn't displayed. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have any setters and getters defined on the User class? If not, try `client.user.game = 'test'`.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. This question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should consider using a [snippet](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using DiscordJS, which I would think from `client.user.setPresence()` existing, you will have to use

```
client.user.setActivity('yourGameNameHere', { type: 'PLAYING' });
```

instead or upgrade to DiscordJS Branch `11.1-dev`. Read my other reply on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907987/discord-js-setgame-not-wroking).

Also see [the GitHub Issue on it](https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/issues/1807#issuecomment-323578919).

Comment: I've rolled back [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46793768/2) for a few reasons. Feel free to make your own answer for this but I don't want to be associated to posting unreleased features which, when used in specific conditions, are a violation of the API ToS.